# Can I upgrade from hobby to Standard 1x just paying the difference?

Tags: salesforce1-app, heroku, heroku-enterprise

I am about to publish my application, and I would like to buy the hobby plan, for the beginning, but with the passage of time, and when my application starts to grow, I know I will need to upgrade to a better dyno ...

My current situation is: Free Dyno.

For example, let's say I buy Dyno Hobby today, and my application grows fast, so tomorrow I need to upgrade to Standard 1x. Today I would pay $ 7 for the dino hobby. And tomorrow, when I have to upgrade to standard 1x, can I only pay the value difference of the 2 dynes?

Hobby $ 7 Standard 1x $ 25

Will I pay to upgrade to standard 1x, $ 18? (7-25 = 18) Or do I have to pay for the 2 dynos? $ 32 (7 + 25 = 32)

Maybe I will not use Hobby's plan for long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charges are pro-rated, so if you were to switch to a Standard-1X dyno half way through the month, you would only be charged $12.50 for the second half of the month (1/2 of the $25 Standard-1X). The next month, there would be a $25 charge for the entire month. You can read more here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/usage-and-billing